# how can I quickly add WMC functions to my Logitech Harmony One remote?

Tags: windows-media-center, universal-remote

I have a Logitech Harmony One that I'd like to use to control Windows Media Center. I have a WMC remote and a receiver that I'm currently using. So I *could* program all those buttons via the learning feature, but ugh.

Is there a quick way to load the WMC remote functionality into the Logitech remote and then use the Logitech remote to control WMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, found it shortly after I posted this:

Add a new device:

```
Device type: Computer -> Media Center PC
Manufacturer: Microsoft
Model: Windows Media Center SE
```

Works good so far.